# How to fix javavascript error from browser and improve error logging

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-events

Shopping cart page rendered in browser contains error logger:

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    $.post('/Home/Error',
    {
        "errorMsg": errorMsg,
        "url": url,
        "lineNumber": lineNumber,
        "column": column,
        "errorobj": JSON.stringify(errorObj)
    });
```

which logs errors to Mono MVC4 application in server:

```
    public ActionResult Error(string errorMsg, string url,
        string lineNumber, string column, string errorobj)
    {
        Logifail.Write(
            string.Format(
            "Error {0}\n" +
            "Url {1}\n" +
            "Line {2}\n" +
            "Column {3}\n" +
            "Obj {4}\n", errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorobj
            );
        return new ContentResult();
    }
```

Server logs contain lot of messages

> Error Object doesn't support this property or method
> Url http‍://example.com/Store/Details?product=H62810-00
> Line 132
> Column
> Obj

line 132 contains `var price = Number($('#Price').text().replace(',', '.').trim()),`
This line is in method which updates price in cart:

```
   var updatePage = function () {
        var price = Number($('#Price').text().replace(',', '.').trim()), // line 132
          quantity = Number($('#spinner').val().replace(',', '.'));
        var total_eur = price * quantity;
        $('span#total_eur').text(total_eur.toFixed(2));
    };
```

it looks like something is wrong sometimes in this line.
How to fix this error ? I tried possible users interactions in this page which call this method but error does not occurs. This error occurs in some users only.

Can `updatePage()` be changed so that error does not occur?
How to log more information about Javascript error in browser: Javascript stack trace, variable names and current and other data from browser which can provide more information about the error?
`column` and `errorobj` are always empty. Why those are not passed to error handler?

jQuery, jquery-ui with some plugins are used. The following files are loaded into page in minified form:

```
      "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js",
      "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js",
      "~/Scripts/menubar.js",
      "~/Scripts/jBreadCrumb/js/jquery.jBreadCrumb.1.1.js",
      "~/Scripts/Pikachoose/jquery.fancybox.js",
      "~/Scripts/jquery.dotdotdot-1.5.6-packed.js",
      "~/Scripts/responsiveslides.js",
      "~/Scripts/jcarousel-0.2/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.trim()` is not supported in IE8 so this is more than likely the reason you only see it with a few users.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim suggests the following Polyfill

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  (function(){
    // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
    var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
      return this.replace(rtrim, "");
    }
  })();
}
```

here is the support options for `.trim()`

```
Chrome  | Firefox (Gecko)   | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari
-----------------------------------------------------------------
(Yes)   |   3.5 (1.9.1)     |        9          | 10.5  | 5
```

Comment: thank you. How to  improve error logging: log call stack and javascript source line where exception occurs ?

Comment: looking at you can't get much more information from your logs. onerror does not receive an error object and as such you there for can not get a stack trace, here is a good article discussing options http://blog.meldium.com/home/2013/9/30/so-youre-thinking-of-tracking-your-js-errors